# How can I solve "The Network Analyst solver could not determine a solution"?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, error, network-analyst

[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

I have network data for undulated terrain so there are lots of inaccessible parts of the  network.
When I was using this model, I get "The Network Analyst solver could not determine a solution" error. I'm not aware how to solve this error. I have attached an example image to show the problem.

I am looking for your guidance.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are settings of your analysis? You're saying that a lot of parts of your network are inaccessible. What if you trying to route through a stop that is inaccessible (it has been located on inaccessible edge)? Have you tried doing this analysis step by step and see on which step exactly do you get that error. I would advise you to clear your dataset from inaccessible edges (what are they there for?)

Comment: Thanks your advise Mr.jareks , So which step i want use 1st level? I had used only two conditions route and stops. May i know proper steps? im not that much experience regarding module builder that is the issue.

Comment: I would not start with using model builder straight away. Try making those analysis step by step outside of model builder. Examine your network, find disconnected parts and remove them. I would use model builder only when you're certain what you're doing, and you just want to automate your analysis. Make sure you understand ideas behind network analysis in ArcGIS as not all of them are that intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error says, you have problems with the network dataset itself not the Route layer or solving the model. I'd try several things:

1) Add a network dataset to ArcMap and when prompted do not add any source features. Does it draw correctly and has edges? If yes, then the network dataset has been built properly.
Try running a simple test of routing between two points in ArcMap with the network dataset before taking the network dataset into a model.

2) Create a new file geodatabase with a new feature dataset. Use the Feature Class to Feature Class GP tool to convert the Streets feature class. Build a new network dataset there just to test it would work in a "fresh" environment.

3) Did you upgrade a network dataset from 9.3 to 10 recently? Do you store your network dataset in a geodatabase of 9.3 version or 10?

4) If the network has no edges perhaps it needs to be "built". Did you build the network dataset before using it (can be done in Catalog window of ArcMap or ArcCatalog)

5) I've seen this issue once with the proper network dataset - the problem gone away after installing SP3 for 10.0. Do you have SP3? If nothing helps, could be a good time to update maybe to the latest SP (SP5).

6) Also keep in mind that if the network dataset has none of the edges available then the stops you load have basically no place (no link) where they could [snap to](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/What_are_network_analysis_objects/00470000003n000000/). Therefore you will need to re-load them and re-calculate their locations once the edges are in place.

Since you have lots of inaccessible parts of the network in your network dataset, consider using the [query builder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Snapping_network_locations_with_Build_Query/00470000003w000000/) (Route Analysis layer properties window > Network Locations tab) to [exlude locating on certain edges](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/in_ArcMap/00470000003t000000/).

Comment: Thanks Mr.Alex I will try to get result as per your steps

Comment: Very good answer. My workaround to find disconnected part of network was to create a dense grid of points (by creating raster of fine resolution and extents of my network  - then converting it to points) and running closest facility analysis: with a single facility located in easily accessible part of my network and that grid of points as demand points, and no time cut off. Demand points that didn't have allocated facility helped me to identify disconnected edges.